# Convert Date from DD.MMM.YYYY to YYYY-MMM-DD using xslt 1.0

Tags: xml, date, xslt, transformation, date-formatting

I found a couple of solutions but none for me does not work. 
because it can not be `<template>` in `<template>`. I need convert date inside foreach because `<number requested>` is more about 80 and then is end of export. I need transform and convert Date_Delivery . Any ideas? Please help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1250"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">     

 <xsl:template match="/">
<dat:dataPack version="2.0" id="Usr01" ico="36255789" application="Transformace" note="Užívateľský export" xmlns:dat="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/data.xsd">
       <xsl:variable name="discount" select="0.20" />
<xsl:for-each select="OBERON/Data/InvoicesIssued/Record">
       <dat:dataPackItem version="2.0" id ="{@IDNum}">

        <inv:invoiceType>issuedInvoice</inv:invoiceType>
    <inv:number>
 <typ:numberRequested><xsl:value-of select="@Number"/></typ:numberRequested>
        </inv:number>

            <inv:symVar><xsl:value-of select="@Number"/></inv:symVar>
         <inv:dateTax><xsl:value-of select = "Date_Delivery"/></inv:dateTax>
```

Comment: Consider to provide a [mcve]. It will increase the probability of receiving a useful answer. And get your XML/XSLT _well-formed_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to suppose the following structure:

```
<baseNode>
    <myDate>01.Jan.2017</myDate>
</baseNode>
```

You can use the following to transform:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(/baseNode/myDate, 8, 4), '-',  substring(/baseNode/myDate, 4, 3), '-', substring(/baseNode/myDate, 1, 2))" />
```

Comment: @DominikDravecký You're right, typo. Edited it, should be good now.